# How do I get this Bootstrap navbar to look neat on a mobile device?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

You can see it [live here](http://ognr.herokuapp.com/).

Here is a screenshot on mobile:

[image: Messed-up Mobile Navbar Bootstrap]

Here is the sterilized HTML:

```
    <header class="header">
      <hgroup class="pull-left">
        <h1 class="site-title">
          <a rel="home" title="Von" href="index.html">
            <i class="fa fa-lemon-o"></i> Von
          </a>
        </h1>
      </hgroup>
      <div id="togglesidebar" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </div>

                <!-- Single button -->
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Action <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

            <!-- Search Bar -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-2">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                  <li><a href="#contains">Contains</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#its_equal">It's equal</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#greather_than">Greather than ></a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#less_than">Less than < </a></li>
                                  <li class="divider"></li>
                                  <li><a href="#all">Anything</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- /search-bar -->
  </header> <!-- /header -->
```

In the live version, the logo is `153px X 50px`.

**Update 1:**

After Darshak's suggestion, this is what the mobile version looks like. Better, but still needs adjustment.

[image: Mobile-Menu-Responsive]

Comment: You may want to post your CSS to ask a better question. Just looking at the HTML it will be tough to answer your question. Are you using the default bootstrap css? Some type of theme? Just your HTML isn't completely helpful.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap and a theme. That's why I posted a live link, so you can see it in action - there would be too much CSS to show. Either way, the core problem I believe is with the Bootstrap related classes. There aren't that many theme specific classes in the HTML.

Comment: first of all, you're loading all CSS files twice and compiled in a single file, then on top of that you load normalize after everything (and compile inside that file). So basically, you declare a class, then nullify it by re-declaring it, then, just in case, you kill any choice of Bootstrap classes to work with normalize.css. Clean that file and quite possibly you won't need to do anything else

Comment: @Fabio You are correct that there was a lot of duplicate file loading happening. I reduced the clutter, and now there is just one instance of Bootstrap and the other CSS files loading, yet I still have the layout issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. i try to responsive look to your design and some class modified in your structure.
i put this structure online at your given link.

```html
<header class="header clearfix">
  <div class="row masthead clearfix">
    <hgroup class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <div class="site-title">
        <a href="/">
          <img alt="Ognrlogo" height="50" src="/assets/ognrlogo-232e94e86f40eeb3021490f5cf1e1a48.png" width="153" class="img-responsive" style="
    margin: 0;
">
        </a>
        <br>
        <span class="">On The Ground News Report</span>
      </div>
    </hgroup>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2 masthead-group-2 text-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!-- <li class="dropdown"> -->
        <!-- <li>  </li> -->
        <!-- <li> </li> -->
        <!-- </li> -->
        <!-- <li>  </li> -->
        <!-- <li>  </li> -->

        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Login &amp; Join
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/login" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/register" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Join</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /dropdown-parent-div -->

    <!-- /search-box-parent -->


    <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-4 col-lg-4 masthead-group-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span>  <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#contains">Contains</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#its_equal">It's equal</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#greather_than">Greather than &gt;</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#less_than">Less than &lt; </a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#all">Anything</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-3 col-lg-3 masthead-group-3">
      <!-- <div id="togglesidebar" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </div> -->

      <div id="togglesidebar" class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-child"></i> Submit News</button>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 hidden-md hidden-lg masthead-group-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span>  <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#contains">Contains</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#its_equal">It's equal</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#greather_than">Greather than &gt;</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#less_than">Less than &lt; </a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#all">Anything</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 hidden-md hidden-lg masthead-group-3">
      <!-- <div id="togglesidebar" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </div> -->

      <div id="togglesidebar" class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-child"></i> Submit News</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /row -->
</header>
```

Comment: I tried your changes, and updated the question with the results. Almost there, but still some issues. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this and modify your source code according to that

***http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar***

You can do like this , to look it better on mobile devices.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Just a demo,  #copied from getbootstrap.com